# How to prove $\sin(\frac{1}{x-1})$ is not uniformly continuous?

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

Lets say I need to provide a function that is bounded and continuous on the interval $(1,2)$ but not uniformly continuous on this interval and I have to prove it.

I know the distinction that continuity is defined at a point $a$, whereas uniform continuity is defined on the entire interval. But how do I visualise this? In wikipedia's example, it says something about fitting a point inside a rectangle. Does not-uniformly continuous function revolves around the idea of steepness?

If a function is very steep the $\delta$ cannot catch up to $\epsilon$. So in here, can I say the function f(x) is $\frac{1}{x-1}$? So something like:

[image]

This is still count as continuous because $x$ is defined on an open bracket $(1, 2)$ right? and It is not uniformly continuous because of the steepness in the interval?

Can someone verify this? Is this correct? If so how do I prove that it is not uniformly continuous? I am planning to assume it is uniformly continuous and work from the definition. Can someone give me a hint on how to prove this?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem bounded.

Comment: Go for $x\mapsto\sin\left(\frac1{x-1}\right)$ to make it bounded as well.

Comment: @drhab Hello, why does adding $\sin$ makes it bounded?

Comment: @drhab Are there other ways of making this bounded? Or what could be some other solutions that might be easier than this because I am struggling to prove it. Many thanks.

Comment: with the example suggested, try showing that $$f(1+\frac{1}{\pi/2 + 2\pi n}) - f(1+\frac{1}{2\pi n}) =1$$.

Comment: On the question in your first comment: we have $|\sin f(x)|\leq1$ so functions like that are always bounded. On the question in the second: I don't think it can be done on a way that is essentially easyer. Anyhow, you received answers now and I hope they are useful for you.

Comment: @username Hi thanks for answering, why did you add $1$ or rather how did you get $1 +$ ? So from my attempt I tried $x = \frac{1}{\frac{-\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$ and $y = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$. Does this work? I don't understand how you got your $x$ and $y$ values. Many thanks username

Answer (score 1):

Supose you have $f:(a,b) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is uniformly continuous and two sequences $(x_n)_n,(y_n)_n \subseteq (a,b)$ such that $|x_n-y_n| \overset{n}{\rightarrow} 0$. Then it's easy to verify that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\overset{n}{\rightarrow} 0$.

So if we take $f:(1,2) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=sin(\frac{1}{x-1})$ and find two sequences $(x_n)_n,(y_n)_n \subseteq (1,2)$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|$ doesn't approach $0$ then $f$ can't posibly be uniformly continuous. I think this is one of the easier ways to show what you want.

From that, take $x_n, y_n$ such that $\frac{1}{x_n-1}=\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n,\; \frac{1}{y_n-1}=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n$.

You will find that $x_n,y_n \rightarrow 1$ and therefore $|x_n-y_n|\rightarrow 0$
but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|=2$. So $f$ cannot be uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\sin \frac {1}{x-1}$ for $x\in (1,2)$.

Given any $\epsilon\in (0,1),$ and any $\delta >0,$ take some $n\in \Bbb N$ with $n\pi>1/\delta$ and let $x=1+\frac {1}{n\pi}$ and let $y=1 +\frac {1}{(n+1/2)\pi}.$ Then $x,y\in (1,2)$ and $|x-y|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(y)|=1>\epsilon.$

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for answering. I don't understand your $x$ and $y$ choices. So from my attempt I tried $x = \frac{1}{\frac{-\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$ and $y = \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$. Does this work? I don't understand how you got $1 + \frac{1}{\pi n}$ and your $y$ Many thanks again

Comment: (i). If $x=1+1/(n\pi)$ then $1/(x-1)=n\pi$ and $f(x)=\sin n\pi=0...$  (ii).The idea is that for any $\delta >0$ the set $S(\delta)= \{1/(x-1): 1<x< 1+\delta\}= (1/\delta,\infty)$ is a half-line so $\{f(x):1<x<1+\delta\}=\{\sin t : t\in S(\delta)\}=[-1,1].$ For convenience I just took some $x,y \in (1,1+\delta)$ with $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=\pm 1.$

Comment: Hi Mr Wainfleet, thanks for answering. I now understand the first part. I don't get how you can just conclude $|x-y|<\delta$, is true. I cannot see the implications that make this true. I don't have to substitute $x$ and $y$ into $|x-y|<\delta$ right?

Comment: $|x-y|=x-y=\frac{1}{n\pi}-\frac{1}{(n+1/2)\pi}<\frac{1}{n\pi}<\delta$ because $n\pi>1/\delta. $ Note that we are not looking for the least possible $n$, just any $n$ that's big enough to make the argument work.

Comment: Take a look at the graph of $f(x)$ for $x$ very close to $1$.